# Get record in many to many table with null row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables

```
 1. Employee
 2. Calendar
 3. Check-in/out
```

`Check-in/out` have two foreign key `emp_id` from `Employee` and `cal_id`. Now Problem is how get the record of `Employee` not in table `Check-in/out` with date in calendar.

Simply say, get employee Absents record

Comment: Please be more specific.  Check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's relatively clear. He wants a list of employee + dates where these employee were absent, so where there is no record in the relation table for that calendar-date-employee combination. However, it would help if you'd show sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a `CROSS JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.*, c.*
FROM Employee e
CROSS JOIN Calendar c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM [Check-in/out] cio
    WHERE cio.emp_id = e.emp_id
    AND   cio.cal_id = c.cal_id
)
```